# Python + selenium как достать текст со страницы?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautiful-soup

Делаю проэкт на курсах Python. Написан парсер для сайта с помощью BeautifulSoup.
Есть страница товара где что бы получить цену нужно найти кнопки и сделать 2 клика(выбрать скажем цвет и комплект товара) для того, что бы это сделать решил использовать модуль selenium для Python. После кликов получаю что то типо

```
<span id="j-sku-price" class="p-price">340.99</span>
```

Теперь нужно достать эту цену. Если вытаскивать посредством BeautifulSoup, то он не получает данных о кликах(просто парсит с полученого адреса на котором это поле не заполнено пока не сделаны клики), так что нужно вытащить ее другим способом.

Нашел команды storeText и getText для selenium но не понимаю как их применить, люди в темах форумов по селениум кидают част кода в формате

`storeText | //div[@class='price'] | productPrice`

Который конечно же не понимается интерпретатором Python. Записывая в понятном для питона виде получаю при разных вариантах записи разные ошибки. В основном что модуль не содержит команд storeText и getText.
Как правильно нужно написть код, что бы вытащить эту цену в среде Python?

Comment: Настоятельно вам рекомендую хотя-бы почитать что такое JavaScript, зачем он используется в вебе, и почему одни задачи решаяются чистым Супом, а другие только Браузером

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ нашел на ангоязычном stackoverflow. Вот так работает:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_id("j-sku-price"):
    print(element.text)
```